# GroupBox Expansion property

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-controls

- In my C# WPF windows Application I used Group Box with some labels and text boxes inside it to insert some data
- I created a button called (add) beside one of text boxes in that Group Box
- I want when I press (Add) button :

  - Group Box Expand in size and
  - a new Text Box appear below the first one to insert more data
  - (Add) button appear beside the new text box
- I wish you could Help me ..Thanks

[image]

Comment: This should not be a problem for you! All you have to do is to take in consideration height and width of your controls on groupbox and to increase them on that button click event. And, for that button position is the same story! You'll have textbox width+separatio between textboxes added to the Add button position. ... This way you'll have a dynamical gruopbox! Hope this will help you to get started?

Comment: @Sylca ... i couldn't get what you mean .. i will be grateful if u explain what u want to tell with codes ...thank you

Comment: Post your code and XAML and we might be able to help you further

Comment: i ask because i couldn't make any code related to it ..i just make the interface of (Normal case) = a group box with text boxes and labels and a button ...just it ..so i came here because i couldn't know what i should do

Comment: @Hatem How many extra lines are you wanting to increase it to?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See if this is what you are wanting, I used `StackPanel's` and a `DockPanel` which will grow as content is added, I also added the 5 extra `TextBox's` and `TextBlock's` with a visibility of collapsed which means that they do not take up any space when not visible. I added them to List's which I then check visiblity when you click your button making the appropriate controls visible at that time.

**MainWindow.xaml**

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="214" Width="525" SizeToContent="WidthAndHeight">
    <Grid>
        <GroupBox Header="General Information"   HorizontalAlignment="Left"  Name="groupBox1" VerticalAlignment="Top">
            <Grid >
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="4*"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="3*"/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <DockPanel Grid.Column="0" HorizontalAlignment="Left" >
                   <Button VerticalAlignment="Bottom"  Height="25"   Click="Button_Click" >Add</Button>
                </DockPanel>
                <StackPanel Name="stackpanelTB" Grid.Column="1"  Orientation="Vertical"  >
                    <StackPanel.Resources>
                        <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
                            <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0,4,0,0"/>
                        </Style>
                    </StackPanel.Resources>
                    <TextBox  Name="textBox1" Width="240" Height="25"></TextBox>
                    <TextBox Name="textBox2" Width="240" Height="25"></TextBox>
                    <TextBox Name="textBox3" Width="240" Height="25"></TextBox>
                    <TextBox Name="textBox4" Width="240" Height="25"></TextBox>
                    <TextBox Name="textBox5" Width="240" Visibility="Collapsed" Height="25"></TextBox>
                    <TextBox Name="textBox6" Width="240" Visibility="Collapsed" Height="25"></TextBox>
                    <TextBox Name="textBox7" Width="240" Visibility="Collapsed" Height="25"></TextBox>
                    <TextBox Name="textBox8" Width="240" Visibility="Collapsed" Height="25"></TextBox>
                    <TextBox Name="textBox9" Width="240" Visibility="Collapsed" Height="25"></TextBox>
                </StackPanel>
                <StackPanel Name ="stackpanelCaption" Grid.Column="2" Orientation="Vertical">
                    <StackPanel.Resources>
                        <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
                            <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0,4,0,0"/>
                        </Style>
                    </StackPanel.Resources>
                    <TextBlock Name="textBlock1" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Height="25">Ingredient ID</TextBlock>
                    <TextBlock Name="textBlock2" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Height="25">Ingredient Name</TextBlock>
                    <TextBlock Name="textBlock3" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Height="25">Chemical Str</TextBlock>
                    <TextBlock Name="textBlock4" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Height="25">Ingredient Salts</TextBlock>
                    <TextBlock Name="textBlock5" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Visibility="Collapsed" Height="25"></TextBlock>
                    <TextBlock Name="textBlock6" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Visibility="Collapsed" Height="25"></TextBlock>
                    <TextBlock Name="textBlock7" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Visibility="Collapsed" Height="25"></TextBlock>
                    <TextBlock Name="textBlock8" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Visibility="Collapsed" Height="25"></TextBlock>
                    <TextBlock Name="textBlock9" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Visibility="Collapsed" Height="25"></TextBlock>
                </StackPanel>
            </Grid>
       </GroupBox>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

**MainWindow.xaml.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic; 
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

namespace WpfApplication1
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        List<TextBox> tboxList = new List<TextBox>();
        List<TextBlock> tblockList = new List<TextBlock>();
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            tblockList.Add(textBlock1);
            tblockList.Add(textBlock2);
            tblockList.Add(textBlock3);
            tblockList.Add(textBlock4);
            tblockList.Add(textBlock5);
            tblockList.Add(textBlock6);
            tblockList.Add(textBlock7);
            tblockList.Add(textBlock8);
            tblockList.Add(textBlock9);
            tboxList.Add(textBox1);
            tboxList.Add(textBox2);
            tboxList.Add(textBox3);
            tboxList.Add(textBox4);
            tboxList.Add(textBox5);
            tboxList.Add(textBox6);
            tboxList.Add(textBox7);
            tboxList.Add(textBox8);
            tboxList.Add(textBox9);
        }

        private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++)
            {
                if (tboxList[i].Visibility == Visibility.Collapsed)
                {
                    tboxList[i].Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
                    tblockList[i].Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: @Hatem My pleasure, still looking at your other one.